# jquery not working in html

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do a jquery ajax tutorial but I'm not able to get it to work.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        //var theme = getDemoTheme();

        var url = "http://localhost/schoollife/services/getchapters.php?a=showdata";

        // prepare the data
        var source =
        {
            datatype: "json",
            datafields: [
                { name: 'curriculam_type', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'class_type', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'subject_type', type: 'int' },
                { name: 'chapter_name', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'chapter_number', type: 'int' },
                { name: 'author_name', type: 'string' },
                { name: 'reviewer_name', type: 'int' }                
            ],
            //id: 'id',
            url: url
        };
        var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
        {
            width: 940,
            source: dataAdapter,
            //theme: theme,
            columnsresize: true,
            columns: [
              { text: 'Curriculum', datafield: 'curriculam_type', width: 100 },
              { text: 'Class', datafield: 'class_type', width: 100 },
              { text: 'Subjects', datafield: 'subject_type', width: 100 },
              { text: 'Chapter', datafield: 'chapter_name', width: 160 },
              { text: 'Chapter Number', datafield: 'chapter_number', cellsalign: 'center',width: 60},
              { text: 'Content Author', datafield: 'author_name'},
              { text: 'Content Reviewer', datafield: 'reviewer_name'},
               { text: 'Edit', datafield: 'Edit', width: 60, cellsrenderer: function () {
                 return '<div style="width:100%"><a href="edit_chapters.html", class="edit_chapters fancybox.iframe"><img src="../images/edit.png"  style="margin-left: 25%"/></a></div>';
             }, 
             },
                { text: 'Delete', datafield: 'delete', width: 60, cellsrenderer:function () {
                 return "<div style='width:100%'><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='**delbutton**'><img src='../Images/delete.png'  style='margin-left:25%'/></a></div>";
             }, 
             },

          ]
        });


 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".**delbutton**").click(function(){ 
        alert('sdsdsd');

            alert('Are You sure you want to delete!');
             evt.preventDefault();
            var id=this.href;
            var url='http://localhost/schoollife/services/getchapters.php?a=deletechapter&chapter_id='+data[i].id;
            $.messager.confirm('Confirm','Are you sure you want to delete record?');
                $.ajax({
                    cache:false,
                    dataType:'json',
                    url:'http://localhost/schoollife/services/getchapters.php?a=deletechapter&chapter_id='+data[i].id,
                    async:false,
                    success:function(data){
                        alert(data);
                    }
                })

        });
    });
    });
```

If I do the same in a .js file I wouldn't have any problem. What am I missing here?
Thanks

Comment: you question is too vague, what is your exact issue?

Comment: are you getting an error ? I assume you know  to add a script tag :) Can you see in your debug pane if the request is being made ?

Comment: I'm assuming you have this code after jQuery

Comment: are you really sure it working in external .js file. i see you have doc ready handler in a doc ready handler.

Comment: do you have them inside `<script tag="text/javascript"></script>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, what about `<script>` tag:

```
<script>
  //js code here
</script>
```

You need of course to place it after including jquery.

Comment: So tell it in your question

Comment: have you include the jquery source? `<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>`

Comment: Let me ask: Have you got error in console? If yes, which one(s)??? BTW, check your network tab for error(s) too

Comment: in your code, is this a typo or what: $(".**delbutton**").  BTW, when you said "it doesn't work", it means really nothing. It's like if i ask you what to do because my car doesn't work

Comment: $(".**delbutton**") is not selector for class=delbutton, it is $(".delbutton"). If you just add ** in your question but it is not in your original code, tell us otherwise we would lose our time to try to fix something which is not related to your problem...

Comment: $(".**delbutton**")  put it in bold for understanding...in original i add $(".delbutton") in that not working jquery

Comment: Sorry, i cannot help you more if you don't post link to see in live your issue

Comment: Thanks i got it..i add $(document).on('click','.delbutton',function()

Comment: So it was a delegation problem, your element was dynamically added to DOM after setting the handler. Cool it works now for you :)

Comment: can u help me one more issue...ids not passing to delete row in html using jquery ajax using json can u send me any links...

Comment: You have:  var id=this.href;   but after you pass data[i].id which following the code you provide seems undefined. Just pass 'id' instead

Comment: still not getting     $(document).on('click','.delbutton',function(){ 
         //alert('sdsdsd');
         
    alert('Are You sure you want to delete!');
     //evt.preventDefault();
    var id=this.href;
    var url='http://localhost/schoollife/services/getchapters.php?a=deletechapter&chapter_id='id;
    //$.messager.confirm('Confirm','Are you sure you want to delete record?');
     $.ajax({
      cache:false,
      dataType:'json',
      url:'url',
      async:false,
      success:function(data){
       alert(data);
      }
     })
     
   });

Comment: Sorry, i won't help you more because i'm quite sure you don't take enough initiative as checking your console... If you want someone to debug your site, hire a developper

Answer (score 0):

you have to close `});`  first document on load function . and consider about open bracket and close bracket